# Is "méndigo" considered offensive?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, vulgaridades

I’ve heard “méndigo” (used in Mexico) but I'm not sure if it's an appropriate word to use. Is it offensive, and if so, does it have this connotation in all countries?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Unfortunately, I must vote to close your question because it is not well posed.  Please, tell us what you think the word means, and tell us how you got that idea.  Also, please include a dictionary definition, with a link.  This could be an interesting question -- but as it stands, it's too skeletal.  Please help us help you.

Comment: Yes, pleas put the word in context, specially because of the accentuation, and clarify if what you feel strange is precisely that (accentuation) or some other aspect of the word like its use for instance.

Comment: The question is plain enough to me, but it’s true that offensiveness depends on context. If I call someone a méndigo in anger, that might offend them even if it’s true.  But if I tell a victim that they person who hurt them is a méndigo, who would be offended?

Comment: Please use a good dictionary before posting here.

Answer (score 18):

The word "mendigo" without an accent is used commonly in Spain to refer to a person that asks for money in the street. It is a standard word and not inappropriate.

The word "[méndigo](https://dle.rae.es/m%C3%A9ndigo)", with an accent, meaning "infamous, very bad", seems to only be used in Mexico according to DLE. We do not use it in Spain.

Comment: It's laudable to want to help people -- but let's not rush in to write an answer when it's not well posed.  We can request clarification, or explain how to write a well-posed question, via comments.

Comment: @aparente001 I do not really understand the problem. This is a question about the word "méndigo", so I explained the only meaning of that word accepted by RAE. The question asks if it is used elsewhere, so I said "no, according to RAE and my experience". I also included the information about "mendigo", because other visitors of the site might confuse the two words if they are not familiar with "méndigo". I cannot think of any interpretation of the question that is **not** answered by this answer, so I would not see the point of not writing the answer. The question is short but not ill-posed.

Comment: @aparente001 But I will be happy to delete or edit the answer if it turns out to be *not an answer to the question* after the OP has added clarification. Feel free to ping me if this happens and I do not get notified otherwise.

Comment: Well, first, about pinging -- it's my understanding that you get notified automatically if I write a comment below a post authored by you. // I'm now confused about whether or not we are confused!  That is, do we feel fairly confident that the OP is asking about the word that has the accent?  (And in this case, perhaps your material about the word without an accent could go in parentheses?)  Or are we still feeling shaky about what exactly OP is asking?

Comment: @aparente001 I meant, feel free to ping me (by commenting here) if the **question** is edited (invalidating my answer) and I do not get notified. I think the question is about "méndigo" with an accent. But it might theoretically be the case that even the OP does not know about the existence of both words.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't see the issue. If op is asking about "méndigo", then this post answers that...if op is asking about "mendigo", then this also answers it

Comment: @wimi I think it is extremely helpful to note a minimal pair based on the presence or absence of accent -- or indeed any other very small change -- and especially so if one of the words is offensive.

Answer (score 7):

> [**méndigo, -a.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=m%C3%A9ndigo)
>
> I.  1.  adj/sust. *Mx, Gu, ES. Referido a persona,* infame, muy mala y vil. pop + cult → espon ^ desp.
>
> 2. sust/adj. *Mx.* Cosa despreciable. pop + cult → espon.

So it appears it is used with this despective connotation in Mexico, Guatemala, and El Salvador.

Comment: Yes, it is heard now and then here in Guatemala. (With accent) It's like saying something matters few to nothing. An approximation could be: "shitty phone" ~= "méndigo teléfono"... Although shitty is a little bit "stronger" that méndigo, so to say. This is a word one should be careful on how and when to use

Answer (score 4):

My husband is a Mexican from the state of Mexico. As far as they're concerned the difference is considerable and if pronounced méndigo, serious offence will be taken. There's nothing considered dishonorable about being a mendigo, but no one wants to be referred to as a méndigo.

Answer (score 0):

Mendigo es el que pide y méndigo el que no da

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25936)

Comment: The expression Juan Flores quotes seems to be an accepted way to differentiate, and I find it helpful.  https://opinion.cooperativa.cl/opinion/politica/mendigo-y-mendigo/2021-04-21/193714.html#:~:text=Hay%20una%20palabra%20para%20el,el%20que%20no%20la%20da%22.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Gracias por su respuesta, seria bueno si tiene una referencia, o simplemente decir que esta es tu experiencia personal.